# Trust self-signed certificate | express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

When trying to login to my page on firefox (no error on chromium based browsers) I get the error

> ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
> at the options-request.

I tried adding `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` to the backend and also added `rejectedUnauthorized`

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem', 'utf8'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }, app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, Firefox doesn't recognize the root authority of your self-signed certificated. To avoid this warning from Firefox, you can [add the generated root certificated to the list of trusted root certificate](https://support.kaspersky.com/CyberTrace/1.0/en-US/174127.htm).